# How to insert JSON data to sql server without converting into Java beans

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, json

My requirement is like, i have a json file data as below.,
{Key1: value1, key2: value 2,....} with file name example.json

It should be inserted into sql server as,
Take name: example
Data as below,
Id     key1    key2
1    value 1 value 2

I'm searching for a solution such that, there won't be any Java layer complexities, like first converting this data into Java beans then inserting into sql using java database drivers...

Implementation should be language and database independent. In future if i change my database server, then it should be a minimal change.

The coupling should be very loose. Like if i introduce a new key in JSON file, that should be minimal change in the solution.

Tia

Comment: Can you show us what your current implementation looks like? this is a very broad question and it would be useful to have a more specific issue to try and address.

Comment: My current implementation is like i have 2 applications.
From application 1 i have java beans which are converting into JSON data at the end.
Then from http request from application 2, I&#39;m accessing this json data and converting back to java beans and inserting into sql server using hibernate..
Application 1 uses java , hibernate and jboss server
Application 2 used Java, hibernate and weblogic..

Answer (score 0):

So, use some library that can do http request to the server. For eg, if you want insert your json data to server in android app , then use simple libraries like Volley , OkHttp etc. 
Problem with your question is , we dont know which server you r using and what application you are doing,, and which programming language you wanna use,, So, im assuming is java android,,